# Numerically integrating $\int_{20}^\infty\frac{4^{1+4ix}\Gamma(-4ix)e^{-2ix}}{(-2i)^{-4ix}}dx$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, mathematica

I want to compute the following integral numerically in Mathematica,
$$\int_{20}^{\infty} \frac{4^{1+4ix}\Gamma(-4ix)e^{-2ix}}{(-2i)^{-4ix}}dx$$
The problem is that when evaluate the integral from $20$ to like $200$, Mathematica gives

> Catastrophic loss of precision in the global error estimate due to insufficient `WorkingPrecision` or divergent integral.

but when I break the integral into several pieces and integrate numerically over intervals $$(20,25),(25,35)+\dots+(190,200)$$ and add them up, I get a finite answer. It is not possible to break the integral to several pieces all the way to infinity so I want to numerically integrate this integral from $20$ to infinity without breaking that apart. Could you please help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should write your question there: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Mathematica is saying this because your integrand is highly oscillatory, and to me, not even obviously convergent. If you split it into two integrals, one integrating $\Re (f(x))$ and the other $i\Im (f(x))$, then you should get better results.

Comment: The integral converges, but slowly: the integrand is $O(x^{-1/2})$ in absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

As @KStarGamer commented, there is no way to say if the integral will converge or not.

Hoping to make life easier, I simplified the integrand
$$f(x)=\frac{4^{1+4ix}\Gamma(-4ix)e^{-2ix}}{(-2i)^{-4ix}}=4^{1+6 i x} e^{2 (\pi -i) x} \Gamma (-4 i x)=$$
$$4 e^{2 \pi  x}  \cos \big[2(6 \log (2)-1)x\big]\,\Gamma (-4 i x)+ i\,\, 4 e^{2 \pi  x}  \sin\big[2(6 \log (2)-1)x\big]\,\Gamma (-4 i x)$$ which did not make any difference with any of the CAS or integration tools I have been able to use.

Doing the same as you did, that is to say computing numerically
$$S_p=\sum_{k=2}^p \int_{10 k}^{10 (k+1)} f(x) \, dx$$
Look how chaotic are the partial sums
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
p & \Re(S_p) & \Im(S_p) \\
 2 & 0.108953 & +0.022820 \\
 3 & 0.113746 & -0.096633 \\
 4 & 0.112116 & -0.087309 \\
 5 & 0.050178 & -0.060335 \\
 6 & 0.096228 & -0.009431 \\
 7 & 0.121693 & -0.052570 \\
 8 & 0.115593 & -0.060880 \\
 9 & 0.104341 & -0.021764 \\
 10 & 0.091119 & -0.072073 \\
 20 & 0.105419 & -0.042355 \\
 30 & 0.086591 & -0.058269 \\
 40 & 0.078336 & -0.045741 \\
 50 & 0.081443 & -0.050922 \\
 60 & 0.094577 & -0.039728 \\
 70 & 0.092210 & -0.039019 \\
 80 & 0.089834 & -0.038934 \\
  90 & 0.083845 & -0.042020 \\
 100 & 0.083572 & -0.047953 \\
 200 & 0.085813 & -0.047719
\end{array}
\right)$$